# OpenTelemetry Nodejs - connecting collector to instrumentation

Tags: node.js, open-telemetry

I am trying to set up a tracing installation for the Hello world example from Lightstep https://lightstep.com/blog/opentelemetry-nodejs/:

```
const express = require("express");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || "8080";
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World");
});

app.listen(parseInt(PORT, 10), () => {
  console.log(`Listening for requests on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

My tracing.js looks as follows:

```
'use strict';

const opentelemetry = require('@opentelemetry/api');
const { NodeTracerProvider } = require('@opentelemetry/node');
const { BatchSpanProcessor } = require("@opentelemetry/tracing");
const { CollectorTraceExporter } = require('@opentelemetry/exporter-collector');
const { registerInstrumentations } = require('@opentelemetry/instrumentation');
const { autoinstrumentationsnode } = require('@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node');

module.exports = () => {
 const provider = new NodeTracerProvider();

 const exporterOptions = {
  serviceName: "my-service-name",
  url: "http://localhost:4317",
 }


 const exporter = new CollectorTraceExporter(exporterOptions);
 provider.addSpanProcessor(new BatchSpanProcessor(exporter));
 provider.register();

 registerInstrumentations({
  instrumentations: [
    new autoinstrumentationsnode(),
  ],
 })
 return opentelemetry.trace.getTracer("instrumentation-example");
}
```

My collector is listening on the localhost:4317, the config file is as follows:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: "localhost:4317"

exporters:
  logzio:
    account_token: token

processors:
  batch:

extensions:
  pprof:
    endpoint: :1777
  zpages:
    endpoint: :55679
  health_check:

service:
  extensions: [health_check, pprof, zpages]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logzio]
```

I am running otelcontribcol_darwin_amd64 version 23. It sends the traces to my logz.io account. It works for Java and Python apps.

With node.js I am stuck. The terminal says the node is running on localhost:8080, but it just doesn't send any traces anywhere. When I change the output to console, it does show me the traces. So the problem is somewhere in the communication between the collector and instrumentation.

Could you please advise as to what I could try to fix this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

where did you find the collector url `http://localhost:4317`? That is incorrect configuration. As of today port 4317 is reserved for [grpc](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/cda019f1a73fcd7528256ce88beafb3a8e30d664/receiver/otlpreceiver/factory.go#L33) and 55681 for [http](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/cda019f1a73fcd7528256ce88beafb3a8e30d664/receiver/otlpreceiver/factory.go#L34). And when you use http for sending telemetry you should configure your url for each signal (trace/metric/log) as suggested [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/c8e28f264c9b293a9bf2b0e7a78c54a962c46650/exporter/otlphttpexporter/README.md#otlphttp-exporter). Updating your collector url with http://localhost:55681/v1/traces should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the example which should be always up to date
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/tree/main/examples/collector-exporter-node

Looking at first I can see that defining "endpoint" in your config is not needed. You can also skip "url" params in "exporterOptions" so the default will be used.

Please try to use the latest version of collector as well, I have been using "otel/opentelemetry-collector:0.30.0" and it works fine for me.